# Mac OS X で OpenOffice.org の extension を開発するには？

Tags: macos, java

今、タイトルの通り、 Mac OS X (Yosemite) で OpenOffice.org の拡張機能を作成しようとしています。

ひとまず、 Java ベースで作成しようとしたのですが、本家サイトのドキュメントが不十分であったり (不十分なように見える)、古かったりして、extension の作成に到れていません。

ひとまず、HelloWorld 的な extension を作りたいのですが、そのために利用できる資料、ないし、サンプルの extension などは、ありませんでしょうか。

Comment: javaのタグを追加しました。

Comment: [こちらのサイト](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/JavaEclipseTuto#Eclipse_and_the_plugin)をご覧ください。確かに古そうな感じがしますし、英語のみですし、丁寧に書いてありますので、コードサンプル等も載せてあります。画像もたくさんありますので、Eclipse経験のある方なら素早くフォローできるでしょう。後、Eclipseでの[OpenOffice開発Plugin](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/JavaEclipseTuto#Eclipse_and_the_plugin)と[OpenOffice SDK](http://openoffice.apache.org/downloads.html)は必要になりますので、ご注意ください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hiroshiさんが言及されているように、[OpenOffice NetBeans Integration](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/OpenOffice_NetBeans_Integration)を利用してOpenOfficeの拡張機能を作ることができました（OS X Yosemiteを利用）。  
以下、具体的な手順です。

1. [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org)のインストール  
   NetBeans 8.0.2をインストールしました。
2. [OpenOffice SDK](http://www.openoffice.org/download/sdk/)のインストール  
   [ダウンロードページ](http://openoffice.apache.org/downloads.html)で**Apache_OpenOffice-SDK_4.1.1_MacOS_x86-64_install_en-US.dmg**をダウンロードしてインストールを実施。
3. OpenOffice NetBeans Integrationをインストール  
   最新のNetBeansだとAvailable PluginsにOpenOffice NetBeans Integrationがないため、[サイト](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/OpenOffice_NetBeans_Integration#NetBeans_8.0_and_Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.x)からプラグインをダウンロードして、NetBeansに追加する（org-openoffice-extensions-4.0.6.nbmをダウンロード）。  
   NetBeansへの追加は[Tools]-[Plugins]-[Downloaded]の[Add Plugins...]から実施。
4. [チュートリアル](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/OpenOffice_Add-On_Project_Type)に従って、プロジェクトの作成、およびOpenOfficeへのExtensionのDeployを実施。

以上でHello World的なextensionを動作させる事ができました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2):

（Bucaran さんのリンクもありますが、残念ながら、かなり古い感じになっていますのですこし補足させてください。）

Eclipse のほかに、 [Netbean を利用した開発](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/OpenOffice_NetBeans_Integration)も可能ですよ。こっちの方が、ちいとはましかなあ・・・。本当に、現在の OpenOffice の開発ドキュメントは古い物と新しい物が混然となっていて混乱を招きます。開発サンプルなどを入手しようとしても、ソース管理サーバ自体が死んでるではないですか・・・

私のおすすめとしては、 Libre Office の方のサンプルを利用することです。 Open Office と Libre Office は元は同じ物で、共通点が非常に多いです。なかには、サンプルを数行変えるだけで動く物も見つかるでしょう。なにより関連ドキュメントが生きているのが、大違いです。

サンプル入手は、[Libre Office SDK Document](http://api.libreoffice.org/examples/examples.html)を参考にしてください。